# will this function call always wait for script that is loaded asynchronously and then excute?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

How do I ensure that the conversion function(defined in myjs.js) always executes? Is there a scenario in which it can fail since it is called before the myjs.js is loaded?

```
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
   //call a function within myjs.js
   $("#id").conversion({
           settings : url
    });
});
</script>

/*loading myjs.js asynchronously*/
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function(){
    var a = document.createElement('script');
    a.type = 'text/javascript';
    a.async = true;
    a.src = 'http://mydomain/myjs.js'; 
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
})();
</script>

</body>
```

Is this a correct way of ensuring that conversion function is always called?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://mydomain/myjs.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true, // otherwise will get fresh copy every page load
  success: function() {
    // script loaded, do stuff!
     $("#id").conversion({
               settings : url
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `$(function(){` means jQuery has loaded, not necessarily your other scripts. So, just having this does not guarantee your function will run after your script has loaded. Thus your function can be called before your script is loaded.

To solve the issue, you need something like:

```
(function() {
    function async_load(){
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = 'http://yourdomain.com/script.js';
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    }
    if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent('onload', async_load);
    else
        window.addEventListener('load', async_load, false);
})();
```

See: http://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/ for more information.

**EDIT TO CLARIFY IDEA AND IMPROVE EXAMPLE**:

This should work since it waits for the page to load, then loads your async, and once it is loaded triggers a function that you can call your external functions of the loaded file in.

Start with loading your script async:

```
(function(){
    var a = document.createElement('script');
    a.type = 'text/javascript';
    a.async = true;
    a.src = 'http://www.example.com/somefile.js';
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
})();
```

Next, do something like this:

```
function my_initialization_function() {
    //call a function within myjs.js
   $("#id").conversion({
           settings : url
    });
}

    if(document.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("load", my_initialization_function(), false );
    }
    else if(window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onload", my_initialization_function());
    }
```

Explanation:
`(document.addEventListener)` adds an event listener for the browsers that support it (all non IE browsers). `(window.attachEvent)` for browsers that instead support attachEvent (IE browsers)

Comment: This code will cause the async_load to get called once all the resources on the page gets loaded. I guess then my function will execute before this script is loaded - And still the problem exists?

Comment: You call your function after the attachEvent is complete.

Comment: any example of how I can do that?

Comment: Makes sense to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're loading it asynchronously you need to ensure it has been loaded before running your code (presumably with and onload callback on the script element?). Or you could just include the script the "normal" way:

```
<script src="myjs.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#id").conversion({
            settings : url
        });
    });
</script>
```

Edit: If you place all your `script` elements just before the closing `</body>` tag the whole page will be loaded before the script is anyway and then there's no harm in "normal" loading. Also, by placing all your script last in the page you don't need to run it on "dom ready" since the dom will already be loaded.

Edit: You may be able to swap dom ready with window loaded as well (not sure tho):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#id").conversion({
        settings : url
    });
});
```